# Contact Manager Database design

Tags: database, contacts

I need to create an ER where users can add and delete their personal contacts.

- Contacts can be any person including other users.
- Users can also check who of the other users have added them to their contact list.

I don't know how to start. Can someone please help me draw this ER?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you elaborate on this question a bit? It's a little vague in what you want.

Comment: I need to design an ER for a system where a user can login, add or delete a contact.A contact can be any person or another user.
Each contact should have a name multiple phone numbers and emails and addresses.

Thank you for your time.
A user can also see who of the other users have added him as a contact.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person
PersonID (PK)
OtherUserInfo...

Contact
PersonId (FK to UserID)
contactId (FK to ContactID) Composite PK these 2 together.

PersonProfile
PersonID  (FK to userID)
PersonCategoryID (FK to UserCategoryID) Composite PK these 2 together. 

PersonCategory
personCategoryID (PK) 
PersonCategory (User, Contact etc) depending on if a user can be a contact or just a contact or just a user.
```

when a user adds a contact the entry is put in Person table and an associated record is in personProfile with a personcategoryID for contact and the contact is linked to the person putting in the etnry via contact table

If a person is added as a contact from the other users, (found by joining person to personprofile where personcategory links to "user" entry, then an entry is saved in contact with the personId doing the seach and the personid of the contact they just added.

if a person is removed from personporfile as a contact, all entries in contact table for that contactId are removed as that person is no longer a valid contact. (assuming history isn't needed)

Just my thoughts... there's lots of ways to skin this cat based on additional requirements, desired growth etc.